# Can tdiQuestion be added to TaskDialog.MainIcon?

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, delphi-2009, taskdialog

Can tdiQuestion be added to TaskDialog.MainIcon? Unavailability of the "?" icon in the TaskDialog renders it almost useless.

Is there any fix?

Answer (score 4):

The reason that there is no *tdiQuestion* option for the MainIcon property is that the TaskDialog is a wrapper around the new *[TaskDialogIndirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544(VS.85).aspx)* function introduced with Vista, and the *[TASKDIALOGCONFIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787473(VS.85).aspx)* structure this function uses provides no *TD_ERROR_ICON* in its *pszMainIcon* field.

If you read the **Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines**, specifically the section on [Confirmations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511273.aspx) you will notice that the question icon has been deprecated for a long time, so it is only fitting that the task dialog does no longer provide it, even though it is still supported for *[MessageBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(VS.85).aspx)* for reasons of backwards compatibility.

You will notice that the task dialog with the "Do you want to save changes to Untitled?" question in the documentation linked above does come without icon, so that's probably the proper thing for you to do as well.